# Upload image as byte array to server in folder

Tags: c#, xamarin

my question is how to upload byte array to server ?

I am already convert it to byte array like this :

```
Stream stream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(data.Data);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(stream);
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 50, memStream);                
byte[] picData;
picData = memStream.ToArray();
```

Now I want to upload picData to the server in folder "pics"

Comment: Who wrote the server code? if you, then please add the listing.

Comment: What kind of server is it?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Do you want to upload it via a web service you wrote or via FTP etc? Or is that code on a website and you simply want to save it to the pics folder within the website?

Comment: Your question is to broad. Please provide as much info as you can so people can help you

Comment: there are dozens of questions on SO that address this issue already - please use the search before posting

Answer (score 0):

```
public string UploadToServer(byte[] image)
    {
        try
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(image);
            var i = Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
            string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss");
            string Filename = "IMG_" + time + ".png";
            string UploadPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Image");
            if (!Directory.Exists(UploadPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(UploadPath);
            string NewFilePath = Path.Combine(UploadPath, Filename);
            File.WriteAllBytes(NewFilePath, image);
            return Filename;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your try catch is doing effectively nothing, it will be the same behavior as not having any try catch at all. Why even have it?